# dictionary to table form

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
value_dict = {
  'name': 'suresh', 
  'age':23, 
  'subject': ['tamil', 'english', 'maths', 'science']
}
```

Actually, I need the output in a tabular form as my keys are my headings and values be like,

```
name     age    subject
suresh   23     tamil
suresh   23     english
suresh   23     maths
suresh   23     science
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you want one row per subject value, you have to iterate over `value_dict["subject"]`:

```
for sub in value_dict["subject"]:
    # I leave formatting details to you...
    print("{name} {age} {sub}".format(sub=sub, **value_dict))
```